# Using Boost C++ library to do a regex replace with a custom replacement

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex, boost-xpressive

I can use Xpressive of the Boost library to do some regex replacement like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

void replace(){
    std::string in("a(bc) de(fg)");
    sregex re = +_w >> '(' >> (s1= +_w) >> ')';
    std::string out = regex_replace(in,re,"$1");
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

What I need is to replace the captured part by the result of a certain transformation function like e.g.

```
std::string modifyString(std::string &in){
    std::string out(in);
    std::reverse(out.begin(),out.end());
    return out;
}
```

so the result of the example provided above would be ***cb gf***.

What do you think would be the best approach to realize this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
std::string modifyString(const smatch& match){
    std::string out(match[1]);
    std::reverse(out.begin(),out.end());
    return out;
}

void replace(){
    std::string in("a(bc) de(fg)");
    sregex re = +_w >> '(' >> (s1= +_w) >> ')';
    std::string out = regex_replace(in, re, modifyString);
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

[live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1qEydG%240)

In documentation there is all about `regex_replace` function [view Desctiption/Requires](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/xpressive/regex_replace.html)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the formatter function into `regex_replace`.  Note it needs to take `const smatch &`.

```
std::string modifyString(smatch const &what){
    std::string out(what[1].str());
    std::reverse(out.begin(),out.end());
    return out;
}

std::string out = regex_replace(in,re,modifyString);
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.string_substitutions